# Out of memory error because of giant input data

Tags: python-3.x

I am using RandomForestClassifier in python to predict whether the pixel in the input image is inside the cell or outside it as a pre-processing stage to improve the image , the problem is that the data size of the training set is 8.36GB and also the size of the test data is 8.29GB so whenever I run my program I get (out of memory) error. Will extending the memory not work?. Is there any way to read csv files which contain the data in more than one step and then free the memory after each step?

Comment: Are you using 32 or 64 bit python?

Comment: Actually, I am using Python 3.5. I think it is 64 but I didn't find this information in the description.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you are using pandas to process this csv file as it would be nearly impossible in native python. As for your memory problem here is a great article explaining how to process large csv files by chunking the data in pandas.
http://pythondata.com/working-large-csv-files-python/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. The program has been running for two hours and till now I haven't gotten any result or error. I don't know whether that is normal or not?

Comment: I got this error :
OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) disk I/O error ............... can you please direct me to understand the possible reasons of such an error

Comment: Without including any code it is impossible to troubleshoot

Comment: yeah absolutely right but I have to add my own code (training the random forest on training data)  and it gave me (return self.cursor.fetchall()

MemoryError)